# fragment: Finding meteorites in woods of Maine

Tags: interpretation, error

Can anyone tell me why the author is using the fragment "Finding meteorites in woods of Maine" here? There's no finite verb in it.

===================

> Darryl Pitt, head of the meteorite division at the Maine Mineral & Gem Museum, said he was keen to study any fragments of the meteorite, which, depending on the type, could contain valuable information about the origins of the solar system. The $25,000 reward is for the first meteorite piece found that weighs 2.2 pounds (1 kilogram) or more. However, he said the museum would be willing to pay for any specimen “irrespective of its size.”

> “**Finding meteorites in woods of Maine. It’s not the simplest of the environments**,” Pitt said.

https://edition.cnn.com/2023/04/12/americas/meteorite-maine-museum-reward-scn/index.html

===================

Curiously, the same story told by People.com presents a complete sentence. But does it make sense there?

> "It's a sparsely populated area but not as sparsely populated as where most meteorites fall — the ocean," Darryl Pitt, who heads up the meteorite division at the Museum, told CNN, adding that "**finding meteorites in woods of Maine" isn't "the simplest of the environments.**"

Comment: . Speech is not writing. That is a quotation not writing by the author pf the article. "Answering questions here. A hard nut to crack".

Answer (score 1):

Can anyone tell me why the author is using the fragment "Finding meteorites in woods of Maine" here? There's no finite verb in it.

1. The author did not write that.
2. The author is quoting the museum director.
3. The speaker he quotes is speaking.
4. That phrase is spoken as if mentioning the topic, which he then does:

"Finding meteorites in [the] woods of Maine. It’s not the simplest of the environments,” Pitt said.

Speech can be like that. Without full sentences. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In casual speech, you can introduce a topic as a noun, then say a sentence about it, probably including a pronoun with that noun as the antecedent. I'm not sure why that writer put a period between "Maine" and "It". If the speaker were transcribing his own words, he probably would have put a comma there.

That's likely why People.com chose to only quote parts of it so they could fit it into one sentence.

Comment: Thank you. But the way People.com puts it suggest that an act (i.e. finding meteorites) **is** a kind of environment. But an act is an act, not an environment.

Comment: Would it be okay to insert "in"? “Finding meteorites in woods of Maine, it’s not **in** the simplest of the environments."

Comment: Yes, that's another problem with this sentence. Again, it's a verbal quote from a non-professional speaker. It's easily understood that he means the environment in which you have to search for meteorites if you're looking for them in Maine isn't the easiest, but that would have taken way too many words. A better correction would be simply, "*It's not the simplest*".  Another separate problem is he should have dropped "the": "*It's not the simplest of **environments***".

Comment: The author isn't *introducing* anything.  The author is quoting what someone else said. “Findin' meteors in woods is a might inter'sen,” Pitt said - Is a perfectly valid quote.

Comment: @EllieK I didn't say that. The speaker, Pitt, introduced the topic of finding meteors in Maine, then continued to say something about it. The author of this article decided --incorrectly in my opinion-- to transcribe "Finding meteorites in woods of Maine" as a complete sentence, rather than a phrase before the main clause.

Comment: Who says the author thinks it's a full sentence. It can be used like a topic which he then comments on.

Comment: @Lambie I mean, the writer transcribed it with a capital letter at the beginning, and a period at the end, like a sentence.

Comment: That does not mean it is a sentence at all. It is like stating a topic and then a comment.

Comment: @Lambie And I never said it did. I've described the fact it was transcribed ***as*** a sentence, which I hope isn't controversial.

Comment: "Yes, that's another problem with this sentence. Again, it's a verbal quote from a non-professional speaker." You react too fast and it is perfectly fine in spoken language. Not everyone who is interviewed is a "professional speaker". The guy is a museum director. He is stating a topic. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The author is not *using* anything.  He is quoting what Pitt said.  People can say anything they like and authors may quote what is said verbatim.  My professor told me, "Text that appears in quotation marks usually represents, verbatim, what someone has said."

> "The rabbit swapped the gopher," said Oscar as he drove away.

What is the author trying to say there?  The author is letting you know what Oscar said as he drove away.  What is Oscar trying to say?  That may be up to you to decide.